# 2 user registration forms

Tags: forms, users

I need to show users 2 registration forms. 2 different forms with different fields. 1 form for free registration and 1 form with admin approval registration. how can i achieve that?

Comment: Do you want to create two profile for the users ?

Comment: @mohit_rocks yes. it would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is not any module that provides this functionality directly. But certainly you can achieve it using other contributed modules.

1. [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2)

   This module allows you to create user profile for the users. You can create profile for the two users like free_registered user and admin_approved users, and can add any number of fields on the user profiles.
2. [Profile2 Registration Path](https://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath)

   This module allows you to set the unique registration path for each profile2 user profile.
   So after installation you will have two registration forms for each profile2 user profiles. You can access this form from the path specified in [Profile2 Registration Path](https://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) module configuration.

Let me know if any issue occurs. :)

Comment: how can i make one registration with admin approval and another without?

Comment: To achieve it you either have to create two registration form or one with some kind of flag that distinguish each other..